# Nginx applying XSLT with proxy_pass

Tags: nginx

My server config

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location = / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8984;
        xslt_stylesheet /path/to/app.xslt;
    }
}
```

nginx was configured --with-http_xslt_module

the stylesheet does not apply,

is there anything else i need to do?

Comment: Check response content-type. See http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_xslt_module.html#xslt_types

Comment: thank you, I had application/xhtml+xml instead of application/xml